# Ignoring Function Arguments if there are NA's

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, arguments

Is the following situation possible in R?

Here is some data and a function:
​

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100,5,5), d = rnorm(100,2,2),
                 c = rnorm(100,10,10))

a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
a <- sample(a, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1))

a<- as.factor(a)
df$a = a

> head(df)
           b          d          c a
1  3.1316480  0.5032860  4.7362991 a
2  4.3111450 -0.1142736 -0.5841322 c
3  2.8291346  3.6107839 16.0684492 a
4 14.2142245  4.9893987 -1.8145138 a
5 -6.7381302  0.0416782 -7.7675387 c
6  0.4481874  0.3370716 17.4260801 a
```

​

Here is the function:

```
my_subset_mean <- function(r1, r2, r3){  
  subset <- df %>% filter(a %in% r1, b > r2, d < r3)
  return(mean(subset$c))
}
```

I can evaluate this function with the following inputs:

```
 my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 
[1] 11.46365
```

**Question:** But is it possible to do the following in R?

​

```
 #example 1
 my_subset_mean(r1 = NA , r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 

#example 2
 my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = NA , r3 = 1 ) 

#example 3
 my_subset_mean(r1 = NA , r2 = 5, r3 = NA ) 
​
```

Can someone please suggest how to do this in R?

Comment: You probably pasted the wrong function, there is no `r1 =`  argument.

Comment: @jay.sf : thank you for your reply! I have added the r1 argument . sorry!

Comment: Great. Now, what should happen in those `NA` cases you describe? Should there any calculation be done? In which way?

Comment: @ jay.sf: thank you for your reply! If i understand correctly, in theory: the mean(subset$c) can still be calculated even if the "r1" argument is left blank. When the "r1" argument is left blank, the rows in "df" corresponding to the conditions specified in "r2 and r3" can then be used to select the corresponding rows from "df" and still return mean(subset$c). I am just not sure how to instruct the function "my_subset_mean" to do this. Could you please show me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use case handling with `if` clauses. Set defaults to `NA` and define what should happen, e.g. use all `a` levels for `r1` and set `r2`/`r3` borders to extremes.

```
my_subset_mean <- function(r1=NA, r2=NA, r3=NA) {  
  if (all(is.na(r1))) r1 <- df$a
  if (is.na(r2)) r2 <- -Inf
  if (is.na(r3)) r3 <- Inf
  s <- subset(df, a %in% r1 & b > r2 & d < r3)
  return(mean(s$c))
}

my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 
# [1] 10.50051
my_subset_mean(r1 = NA , r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 
# [1] 11.0134
my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = NA , r3 = 1 ) 
# [1] 9.024224
my_subset_mean(r1 = NA , r2 = 5, r3 = NA ) 
# [1] 12.84011
```

---

*Data*

```
df <- structure(list(b = c(9.69843582599532, 8.46269535731819, 4.82407895858266, 
6.58444098769932, -1.90602290454891, 0.62137343811342, 0.246206065813347, 
0.793036653531213, 8.77121342495327, -7.44132891058167, 6.0767980203778, 
11.2931613920878, 3.10188736172521, 8.58460261433062, 4.30000646000838, 
11.1761679757397, 10.1886880475286, 4.39613023166472, 6.62616108371428, 
7.12973461820176, 7.06418042730859, 1.41813294429105, 4.45124874431744, 
9.06270943595514, 2.85615985307963, 11.3675141884702, 12.4605228304222, 
-2.62942853280514, -1.05513620642596, -2.82466757798307, 5.47870836189876, 
15.4452896936201, 3.49398693389683, 8.88806953506397, 11.5004092126707, 
8.45253517064691, -4.97987424572937, 11.4487536566939, 10.2306454615809, 
2.5945245314969, 6.3131412115584, 6.69491387932119, 9.81906160221122, 
1.8232549239818, 9.28993104675214, 10.4049121140586, -0.0663306550603622, 
9.43597782121374, -2.69618206231453, 9.81899536383879, 6.65283190982383, 
2.62705531844689, 0.0506821013280137, 1.71469478379078, -2.00948886925582, 
7.11033909303673, 3.6342673960314, -3.85199889555037, 3.837719577011, 
10.5379173614526, 0.241165053988417, 2.98878226744129, 16.5338502557644, 
6.40322268215467, 3.09682071245305, 6.4640882790184, 10.2295103168259, 
-3.54258794150942, 3.57412615661292, 0.847157363296616, 0.958937497233153, 
9.54449804351409, 2.13358415511275, -4.64977595405939, 13.8692102497496, 
12.0947702962328, 10.0054091647506, 5.95099130951445, 13.9878643818839, 
16.656899833379, -2.01250530111107, 10.9738378550877, 5.70649824688106, 
6.23841756803367, 7.89201847081608, 7.43865691287543, 4.25969916370806, 
0.100094919396823, 12.1619498695491, 6.70521010911249, 5.23952320864633, 
6.27893660411319, 1.67615931536556, 8.47111597398358, 10.7407384583375, 
6.6935988330649, 12.8064551325813, 5.06822778652961, 6.18969940741962, 
8.45826815718404), d = c(0.576695372501562, 2.02403852307891, 
4.47302910094982, 1.46591817375579, -1.90112821827422, 2.41840031582007, 
3.90092963341364, 3.1470221849379, 2.39506516190426, 3.18366311180243, 
4.59374236726957, -0.310602591211496, 0.89296227766288, -2.60780517131932, 
3.29393680957706, 1.28194042737137, 4.06048318268274, 2.44158570826126, 
1.05329331360239, -0.149166155095435, 0.777410699269984, 0.720966662138413, 
3.07192930199898, 1.19472321229584, 1.6887709685994, 0.967254843444039, 
-0.094671269353285, 2.45712134247711, 0.506684056027063, 2.61908201167241, 
-0.382807099233013, 2.76118352895658, 4.11734869309253, 2.6251159565002, 
0.890320607632241, 1.31450894352574, -0.162543197930164, -1.245287729716, 
7.54736588980002, 2.50874311708861, 2.42852224699317, 0.396696115747124, 
-2.55570995185874, 2.95066460269776, -1.86568489159839, 1.62344539230723, 
1.38481792508596, 3.92664646129847, 0.798194771588095, 3.02349013522507, 
3.52584742333097, 0.394636796366123, 0.908953662919601, 1.68995871697649, 
3.78699256158826, 3.48105744707364, 0.289938311962986, -1.65615141140493, 
1.73573322264205, 3.3817736811699, 4.83023278077458, -0.00341030149943089, 
-1.9186029474108, 4.62319725720613, 1.70867185021965, 0.890015362641153, 
-1.23390286977168, 3.04207184098186, -0.831917884053825, 4.08268109740385, 
1.55442789102912, 2.387712200986, 2.98273743020262, 1.20107865472766, 
3.91106586582941, 2.83324789816271, 1.78539821303068, -0.601442920761817, 
1.60782713132619, 0.972339568265609, 2.72048427045796, 2.08343673583862, 
2.59627494701068, 0.898957520125343, 3.03113875095081, 2.29259741051018, 
0.48924176893708, 2.21502767325415, -0.699757523015137, 1.86249088436291, 
-1.00274924638415, 0.984005479892101, -3.11310545034708, 2.72294398534204, 
-1.81783882908668, 2.8517333971145, -3.65063013833178, 2.63550421209849, 
-2.10770259607717, -0.830415297865299), c = c(17.019003845757, 
13.3617768297152, 4.48066238288829, 37.4718618472645, 11.1069019480034, 
1.75616658645729, 0.624475582732705, 15.5817026692234, 22.6629232046836, 
18.2802980877926, 6.00913771363243, 8.15814374806181, 9.31214173358088, 
17.0895672083431, 0.775439933083602, 23.4787728977868, -0.350463197592063, 
16.8900893828887, 23.3015857650274, 1.12866295467943, 15.5354333129547, 
5.75102947515029, 4.42405750345341, 10.3803737245953, 0.0651555296711877, 
6.38910987546489, 30.0933493405791, 13.740864245639, 11.5558739730914, 
24.4726877624024, 10.8607475395052, 5.25398069855701, 8.94458272243297, 
7.25290093283984, 11.373274598886, 17.5885131514341, -4.37803727480431, 
17.0367932953449, 24.7891045623381, 29.0664337297521, 9.63122882702153, 
11.8557980079078, 31.7038297074623, 16.7253608016047, 6.76029998330636, 
23.1762935502586, 12.6880697509057, 16.9108435667295, -2.22866021293843, 
10.9820317029724, 18.9173027898193, -0.538613914754789, -7.5854184291672, 
13.238885819089, 11.4241115746851, 15.1327418752124, 4.52304690963654, 
10.5851271075696, 15.8111350966235, 4.68258123673519, 11.2056336002124, 
30.4120838100663, 10.8242493781004, 6.76421873832309, -4.63649032366339, 
15.5832498948434, 23.0268552127803, 25.3043736189912, 7.22967261723758, 
21.4133309352144, 34.017218507608, -2.41446225948565, 0.107422788807282, 
13.8812237056951, 15.1856293259466, 9.58332073588003, 26.0738826140796, 
3.11530220156868, 18.9577216567341, 14.3145186996602, 2.4406205046264, 
15.3651169579063, 17.7414590516619, -0.595045318185088, 22.2098320842764, 
24.7643144506109, 12.4645048262384, 18.1943363251665, 7.71355198959901, 
-0.585098904800947, -7.66751421801502, 14.2940217046492, -2.74480357019551, 
12.1894293122497, 4.44579027604645, -0.191526624075939, 11.3876592877874, 
14.9409323605176, -3.30763960516194, 8.20930867705211), a = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This even works if no argument is specified! e.g.  my_subset_mean(r2 = 5, r3 = 1 )  . Thank you so much!