# R: Adding "NA" factors to the "levels" function

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. In this example, I have the following data:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100,5,5), d = rnorm(100,2,2),
                 c = rnorm(100,10,10))

a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
a <- sample(a, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1))

a<- as.factor(a)
df$a = a


f <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
f <- sample(f, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1))

f<- as.factor(f)
df$f = f

 head(df)
          b        d         c a f
1  6.896434 2.037835  2.867707 e a
2 -3.314758 2.681726 20.038918 d d
3  2.018130 2.229342 -8.341578 c a
4  9.738082 1.127069 18.337212 c c
5  2.442182 3.475735 27.875924 c c
6  5.061937 1.098709  6.166077 a e
```

I then have the following function ("my_subset_mean") that evaluates the "mean" value of df$c for different subsets of "a,b,d,f ":

```
my_subset_mean <- function(r1, r2, r3, r4){  
  subset <- df %>% filter(a %in% r1, f %in% r4, b > r2, d < r3 )
  return(mean(subset$c))
}
```

In a previous question, I learned how to write a loop that evaluates the function  "my_subset_mean" at random subsets of "a,b,d,f " :

```
create_output <- function() {
  uv <- levels(df$a)
  r1 <- sample(uv, sample(length(uv)))
 uv1 <- levels(df$f)
  r4 <- sample(uv1, sample(length(uv1)))
  rgb <- range(df$b)
  rgd <- range(df$d)
  r2 <- runif(1, rgb[1], rgb[2])
  r3 <- runif(1, rgd[1], rgd[2])
  my_subset_mean <- my_subset_mean(r1, r2, r3, r4)
  data.frame(r1 = toString(r1), r4 = toString(r4), r2, r3, my_subset_mean)
}

out <- do.call(rbind, replicate(100, create_output(), simplify = FALSE))

head(out)

             r1         r4        r2         r3 my_subset_mean
1 a, c, b, e, d          d 14.560821  3.4251138            NaN
2          d, e e, d, b, c  9.027482 -1.7108754            NaN
3             d e, b, a, d  1.447395  0.4279652      18.019990
4 a, e, b, c, d          e -6.807861  2.6301878       7.424415
5          a, d          d  8.307980 -1.8923647            NaN
6             a    b, c, a  7.180056 -0.4022791            NaN
```

**Question:** Is it possible to write this loop ("create_output") so that sometimes, values of "r1, r2, r3, r4" are not considered? E.g.

```
             r1         r4        r2         r3     my_subset_mean
1            NA          d     14.56    3.4251138            5
2          d, e, d, b,   NA    NA        -1.7108754         3.1
3             e, b,  d         1.447         NA           18.019990
```

I was thinking that maybe this can be specified within the "levels" statement:

```
uv <- levels(df$a)
  r1 <- sample(uv, sample(length(uv)))
```

Here, we can see the values of "uv":

```
uv
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Can something be done so that sometimes, the function "my_subset_mean" sometimes ignores the some of the subset conditions for "a, b, d,f"? E.g. the "mean" is only calculated using subset conditions on "a,d"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `my_subset_mean` function from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69332677/3962914) to include `r4` value.

```
library(dplyr)

my_subset_mean <- function(r1=NA, r2=NA, r3=NA, r4 = NA) {  
  if (all(is.na(r1))) r1 <- unique(df$a)
  if (all(is.na(r4))) r4 <- unique(df$f)
  if (is.na(r2)) r2 <- -Inf
  if (is.na(r3)) r3 <- Inf
  s <- filter(df, a %in% r1 , f %in% r4, b > r2 , d < r3)
  return(mean(s$c))
}
```

Then change `create_output` function as -

```
create_output <- function() {
  uv <- levels(df$a)
  r1 <- sample(list(sample(uv, sample(length(uv))), NA), 1)[[1]]
  uv1 <- levels(df$f)
  r4 <-  sample(list(sample(uv1, sample(length(uv1))), NA), 1)[[1]]
  rgb <- range(df$b)
  rgd <- range(df$d)
  r2 <- sample(c(runif(1, rgb[1], rgb[2]), NA), 1)
  r3 <- sample(c(runif(1, rgd[1], rgd[2]), NA), 1)
  my_subset_mean <- my_subset_mean(r1, r2, r3, r4)
  data.frame(r1 = toString(r1), r4 = toString(r4), r2, r3, my_subset_mean)
}

set.seed(123)
out <- do.call(rbind, replicate(100, create_output(), simplify = FALSE))
head(out)

#            r1         r4        r2        r3 my_subset_mean
#1            NA          c        NA 4.2164973      12.095431
#2 a, b, c, d, e    b, a, c        NA 0.4394423       7.130999
#3            NA a, c, e, b  9.285701        NA       8.236054
#4            NA         NA 14.060829 3.8960888      10.562523
#5    c, b, a, d         NA        NA        NA       9.015613
#6            NA    a, c, d  2.251218        NA      10.070425
```

Note that currently I have not assigned any probability for occurrence of `NA` value hence the probability of having `NA` as input for any of the argument is 50%. If you want to change that you can assign `probs` value as per your choice in `sample`.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah: Thank you so much for your answer! Would this be the correct way to write the "probs" argument? For example: r4 <-  sample(list(sample(uv1, sample(length(uv1))), NA),  probs(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 .0.2), 1)[[1]]?

Comment: If there were more numeric variables, I think you could just find the range of the smallest value of the smallest variable and the biggest value of the biggest variable? Instead of writing  rgd <- range(df$d) ?

Comment: Actually outside sample is sampling only two values. One is all the non-NA values together as one group and other is `NA`. So you can try `r4 <- sample(list(sample(uv1, sample(length(uv1))), NA), prob = c(0.8, 0.2), 1)[[1]]`. `range` gives smaller and bigger number in a vector.