# R: Is it possible to optimize the following function?

Tags: r, function, optimization

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100,5,5), d = rnorm(100,2,2),
                 c = rnorm(100,10,10))

a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
a <- sample(a, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1))

a<- as.factor(a)
df$a = a

> head(df)
           b          d          c a
1  3.1316480  0.5032860  4.7362991 a
2  4.3111450 -0.1142736 -0.5841322 c
3  2.8291346  3.6107839 16.0684492 a
4 14.2142245  4.9893987 -1.8145138 a
5 -6.7381302  0.0416782 -7.7675387 c
6  0.4481874  0.3370716 17.4260801 a
```

I also have the following function (`my_subset_mean`) which evaluates the mean of the "column c" given a specific choice of inputs:

```
 my_subset_mean <- function(r1, r2, r3){  
      subset <- df %>% filter(a %in% r1, b > r2, d < r3)
      return(mean(subset$c))
    }
    
    my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 5, r3 = 1 ) 
    [1] 5.682513
```

**Question:** Using the `GA` library in R, I am trying to optimize (mixed integer programming) the `my_subset_mean` function, according to the following constraints:

- "r1" can take any combination of ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") , e.g. "a", "a,c", "b, d, e", "a, b, c, d , e", "e, a" , etc.
- "r2" can take any value between 0 and 1
- "r3" can take any value between 0 and 1
- However, `my_subset_mean` can also be calculated with unspecified values of "r1", "r2" or "r3", for example:

```
my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 5, r3 = NA)
my_subset_mean(r1 = NA,  r2 = 5, r3 = NA )
```

etc.

I tried to perform this optimization with the GA library:

```
library(GA)

GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = function(x)  my_subset_mean(x[1], x[2], x[3]),
         lower = c(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 1, 1), upper = c(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 100, 100), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)
```

But I don't think this is the correct way to do it.

Thanks

**What I tried in the past:**

In a previous question ([R: Adding "NA" factors to the "levels" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69339503/r-adding-na-factors-to-the-levels-function) ), I learned how to optimize a similar function using "random grid search":

```
my_subset_mean <- function(r1=NA, r2=NA, r3=NA, r4 = NA) {  
  if (all(is.na(r1))) r1 <- unique(df$a)
  if (all(is.na(r4))) r4 <- unique(df$f)
  if (is.na(r2)) r2 <- -Inf
  if (is.na(r3)) r3 <- Inf
  s <- filter(df, a %in% r1 , f %in% r4, b > r2 , d < r3)
  return(mean(s$c))
}

create_output <- function() {
  uv <- levels(df$a)
  r1 <- sample(list(sample(uv, sample(length(uv))), NA), 1)[[1]]
  uv1 <- levels(df$f)
  r4 <-  sample(list(sample(uv1, sample(length(uv1))), NA), 1)[[1]]
  rgb <- range(df$b)
  rgd <- range(df$d)
  r2 <- sample(c(runif(1, rgb[1], rgb[2]), NA), 1)
  r3 <- sample(c(runif(1, rgd[1], rgd[2]), NA), 1)
  my_subset_mean <- my_subset_mean(r1, r2, r3, r4)
  data.frame(r1 = toString(r1), r4 = toString(r4), r2, r3, my_subset_mean)
}

set.seed(123)
out <- do.call(rbind, replicate(100, create_output(), simplify = FALSE))
head(out)

#            r1         r4        r2        r3 my_subset_mean
#1            NA          c        NA 4.2164973      12.095431
#2 a, b, c, d, e    b, a, c        NA 0.4394423       7.130999
#3            NA a, c, e, b  9.285701        NA       8.236054
#4            NA         NA 14.060829 3.8960888      10.562523
#5    c, b, a, d         NA        NA        NA       9.015613
#6            NA    a, c, d  2.251218        NA      10.070425
```

But can someone please show me how to do this with the "GA" function in R?

Thanks

**Reference:**

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GA/versions/3.2.1/topics/ga

Comment: Is this your actual dataset, or a toy example? If it is the actual dataset, I'd try a complete grid search. If you discretize `r2` and `r3` into 10 levels (plus `NA`), you'd have about 5000 variations to check. Other than that, a generic local-search algorithm (e.g. `NMOF::TAopt`) could handle functions whose inputs are not numeric vectors but arbitrary objects such as lists, matrices, ...

Comment: @ enrico schuman: thank you for your reply! This is a toy data set! Thank you for your suggestion! I will take a look at this function (nmof::TAopt). It can handle factor and numeric inputs? I will try to implement this function on my problem. Maybe if you have time later you can show me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason a local-search algorithm can handle such problems is that solutions are only "touched" by two functions, both of which you have to supply. The *first* is the objective function.

I have slightly rewritten yours:

```
my_subset_mean <- function(x){  
    subset <- df %>% filter(a %in% names(x$r1)[x$r1],
                            b > x$r2,
                            d < x$r3)
    ans <- -mean(subset$c)
    if (!is.finite(ans))
        ans <- 100
    ans
}
```

Instead of three arguments, it only takes one: a list of your original arguments. Also, I assume you want to maximize, so I put a minus in front of the mean. (The algorithm I am going to use later minimizes by default.) If a mean is not finite (NA, NaN), I simply return a large value as a marker for a "bad" solution. Just adjust this to your needs.

Start with an arbitrary but valid solution.

```
tmp <- !logical(length(sort(unique(a))))
names(tmp) <- sort(unique(a))

x <- list(r1 = tmp,
          r2 = 0.5,
          r3 = 0.5)

x
## $r1
##    a    b    c    d    e 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
## 
## $r2
## [1] 0.5
## 
## $r3
## [1] 0.5
```

I recreate your data. (I don't use factors but strings.)

```
library("dplyr")
df <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100,5,5), d = rnorm(100,2,2),
                 c = rnorm(100,10,10))

a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
a <- sample(a, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1))
df$a <- a
```

Evaluate `x`:

```
my_subset_mean(x)
## [1] -11.34132
```

Of course, this result depends on random data. Your numbers will differ.

Now, the *second* function: the neighbourhood. It takes a solution and returns a slightly modified version of it. Again, since you have to provide this function, you have complete control and hence any data structures can serve as input. Here is an example.

```
nb <- function(x) {
    i <- sample(c("r1", "r2", "r3"), 1)
    if (i == "r1") {
        j <- sample(length(x[[i]]), 1)
        x[[i]][j] <- !x[[i]][j]        
    } else {
        x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + runif(1, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)
        x[[i]] <- max(min(1, x[[i]]), 0)        
    }
    x
}
```

The neighbourhood function (i) randomly chooses one
component of the solution, and (ii) randomly changes
that component.  Since `r2` and `r3` behave the same,
the function uses the same code to handle both.  The
neighbourhood also handles the constraints on `r2` and
`r3` by saying `max(min(1, x[[i]]), 0)`: values smaller
than 0 are increased to zero; values above 1 are
reduced to 1. If you want different limits, handle the components separately (i.e. add more `else if` clauses).

```
x  ## original solution
## $r1
##    a    b    c    d    e 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
## 
## $r2
## [1] 0.5
## 
## $r3
## [1] 0.5

nb(x)   ## ... and a neighbour
## $r1
##    a    b    c    d    e 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
## 
## $r2
## [1] 0.5
## 
## $r3
## [1] 0.42586

nb(x)   ## ... and another neighbour
## $r1
##     a     b     c     d     e 
##  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
## 
## $r2
## [1] 0.5
## 
## $r3
## [1] 0.5
```

And that's it. With these two functions (objective and neighbourhood), you can run the actual algorithm. Here, I use Threshold Accepting.

```
library("NMOF")
ans <- TAopt(my_subset_mean, list(x0 = x, neighbour = nb, nI = 1000))

-my_subset_mean(ans$xbest)
```

I hope this gets you started with `TAopt`.
For more on local-search methods, see this [tutorial](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756).
Since you apparently want to filter a data-frame, perhaps this answer is also helpful: [Finding ideal filter setting to maximize target function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377180/finding-ideal-filter-setting-to-maximize-target-function/63429510#63429510) .
Disclosure: I am the maintainer of package [NMOF](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF).

---

Update following the comment:  It is straightforward to expand `nb` for more components. Suppose you wanted larger steps for `r2` and it should be between -5 and 5. Then you could write the function like this:

```
nb <- function(x) {
    i <- sample(c("r1", "r2", "r3"), 1)
    if (i == "r1") {
        j <- sample(length(x[[i]]), 1)
        x[[i]][j] <- !x[[i]][j]
    } else if (i == "r2") {
        x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + runif(1, min = -0.5, max = 0.5)
        x[[i]] <- max(min(5, x[[i]]), -5)        
    } else if (i == "r3"){
        x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + runif(1, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)
        x[[i]] <- max(min(1, x[[i]]), 0)        
    }
    x
}
```

Comment: @ Enrico Schumann : Thank you so much for your answer! Can you please explain why "nI = 1000" and  ans <- 100 ?

Comment: @ Enrico Schumann: If there was another "Factor" variable, I think you should be able to easily adapt the code? E.g. tmp1 <- !logical(length(sort(unique(a1))))
names(tmp1) <- sort(unique(a1))

Comment: @ Enrico Schumann  : for example, if there is another factor variable "r5": nb <- function(x) {
    i <- sample(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r5"), 1)
    if (i == "r1" & (i == "r5") {
        j <- sample(length(x[[i]]), 1)
        x[[i]][j] <- !x[[i]][j]        
    } else {
        x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + runif(1, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)
        x[[i]] <- max(min(1, x[[i]]), 0)        
    }
    x
}

Comment: Is this correct? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think I figured out  why "nI = 1000" and ans <- 100 . I am still trying to figure out: where do you specify the constraints for r2 and r3? thank you so much!